# In DDPM, why can't we get $x_0$ from $x_t$ directly by using equation?

Tags: diffusion-models

In DDPM, when given $x_{t}$ and time step $t$, U-Net predicts $\epsilon$, if I understand correctly, this $\epsilon$ is the exact same $\epsilon$ in equation

$$x_{t}=\sqrt{\bar\alpha_{t}}*x_{0} + \sqrt{1-\bar\alpha_{t}}*\epsilon $$

Since $\bar\alpha_{t}$ is known, and if we have $x_{t}$, we use trained model to predict $\epsilon$, then why can't we get $x_{0}$ directly by using this equation?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the DDPM paper, the mistake is assuming that $\epsilon$ predicted by the U-net is the same $\epsilon$ in $$x_{t}=\sqrt{\bar\alpha_{t}}*x_{0} + \sqrt{1-\bar\alpha_{t}}*\epsilon$$

In the DDPM paper, $$\epsilon$$ always refers to the noise sampled during the forward process, this is "unbiased" noise which is not following some learned gradient to arrive at a location in latent space, it is simply normal (no pun intended) noise meant to distort the original data.

$\epsilon_{\theta}$ is the parameterised noise which is learned and subtracted from a diffusion step in order to converge towards $X_0$

That is why:

$$\epsilon_{\theta}(\sqrt{\bar{\alpha_t}}X_0+\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha_t}}\epsilon,t)$$ is defined as such.

The forward sampled noise is required to calculate the noised sample which the parameterised noise is predicted from.

Comment: Thanks, I can somehow understand you point. But in original DDPM paper, page 4, algorithm 1, step 4 and 5, aren't they the same ε? 
Also in another paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.11970.pdf, the whole derivation 
 in page 15, I think the ε_0 in equation-130 is the same ε_0 the author use for getting x_t from x_0 in equation-69/115.  Correct me if I made another mistake, I'm just getting more confused.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can!

What you wrote makes perfect sense. It is actually given in [original work](https://hojonathanho.github.io/diffusion/assets/denoising_diffusion20.pdf) on page 6 equation 15.

Even more, the process of how the network can reconstruct the $x_0$ is given in [denoising diffusion paper](https://hojonathanho.github.io/diffusion/assets/denoising_diffusion20.pdf) in **Progressive generation** section on page 7. They study exactly the process you are talking about.

This process of image reconstruction is studied even more in work on [perceptual weighted diffusion process](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2022/papers/Choi_Perception_Prioritized_Training_of_Diffusion_Models_CVPR_2022_paper.pdf), it also can be interesting for you to look at!

Hope it helps.